# trying to locate a replacement thermistor

Tags: thermistor

I'm trying to replace a thermistor off a LG lcd tv board.  It has SCK 154 818D on the old thermistor.  I went to shields and they gave me a ceramic capacitor (NTE 90315) and said it would work.  I'm skeptical of this.  My electronic's experience is still in it's infancy at this point.  To date I have not been able to find an exact replacement for it.  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MF72-015D15/317-1216-ND/1190991 this should work as a replacement

Answer (score 2):

More information is needed about the circuit before we can tell you if it works. If you have schematics of part numbers of the TV board that would help.

For starters no capacitor is a drop-in replacement for a thermistor. A capacitor is an energy storage element (if you are new to electronics think of it as a very tiny battery for short term power storage). A thermistor is a resistor that changes value with temperature. My guess is this was somehow part of thermal protection circuitry or as a current inrush limiter to avoid blowing fuses or starting a fire on the LCD board. If this is the case, replacing with a capacitor is not suggested.

Based on the part code for the thermistor (http://www.profusionplc.com/images/data%20sheets/sck-057.pdf) or (http://exvacuo.free.fr/div/Technic/Composants/Thermistor/SCK%20xx%20s%E9rie.pdf) it is not clear what the part is. It may be that you need an NTC thermistor with a resistance of 15 ohms and a current carrying capacity of 4 amps or an NTC resistor with a resistance of 81 ohms and current carrying capacity of 8 ohms.

We would need more information before we could give you a correct answer without worrying that you may blow something up. Can you take pictures of the part or do you have schematics or service manual for the LCD?

Comment: NTC thermistors are used as inrush current limiters.  PTC thermistors are used as resettable (self-resetting) fuses.  [In the context of power thermistors, as opposed to sensor thermistors.]